# awk in solaris 5.8 / get value from two fields/lines

Tags: awk

I'm new to UNIX-Solaris, and I got to make a script and I'm having an issue with a value I require.

Basically I need to detect if two process are running. I find out I can get that info using the following command

```
ps -fu "user" | grep -i "name_oftheprocess/file"
```

When I executed it, I get this info.

```
user   16544 16530   0 08:00:00 ?           0:08 /bin/bash /path/file

user   19098 16544   0 15:44:38 ?           0:00 /bin/bash /path/file
```

So everything is fine here. The thing is I got to compare the 2nd value (16544) from line 1, with the 3rd value (16544) of the 2nd line.  If they match then a message should be sent stating everything is ok; if they don't, something is wrong.

I'm trying to find how with awk I can get those two values separated.
If I use

```
ps -fu "user" | grep -i "name_oftheprocess/file" | awk '{print $2}'
```

it gives me the result

```
16544   19098
```

(this last one I don't need it)

```
ps -fu "user" | grep -i "name_oftheprocess/file" | awk '{print $2}'
```

it gives me the result

```
16530   16544  (this fist one I don't need it)
```

So I want those two values to be stored each one in a separated variable and later compared it with an if sentence.

Comment: You may want to check out `pgrep` and its various flags.

Comment: Also, does Solaris have `/proc`?  (It may be Linux-specific.)

Comment: @Wildcard `/proc` in itself is not Linux specific (a similar hierarchy is available in at least Solaris 11.3), but what Linux puts in it is _very_ Linux specific.

Comment: @Wildcard Linux took `/proc` from Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the info you get into this AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$2}NR==3{print a==$3?"everything is ok":"something is wrong"}'
```

The complete command in your case would be:

```
ps -fu "user" | grep -i "name_oftheprocess/file" | awk 'NR==1{a=$2}NR==3{print a==$3?"everything is ok":"something is wrong"}'
```

**Note:**

This might not be robust! This answer takes your posted text as input, if you provide more details about what you want to do and include the output of the first command, it might be possible to make further considerations and find a more appropriate solution.